# onclick event is broken in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-1.4

I have the following snippet which works as expected:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="return false;">Will go to google</a>
```

Clicking on the href does not take me to google.

But... if I include JQuery 1.4 and wire up a live click event to **anything** on the page (whether it exists or does not) this unrelated event handler stops working as expected in IE (and continues to work in firefox and chrome). Return false is ignored and instead clicking on the link takes you to google.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
          //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".not-here").live("click", function() {alert("hi"); return false; });
    });
          //]]>
 </script>
```

Whats going on? Have I come across a bug in the JQuery 1.4 release.

Comment: This took 2 hours of my time away yesterday, I do not want anyone else to lose those 2 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a **bug** in JQuery 1.4 Release. It affects anyone using the live events.

It was [patched by John](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/b9ca1579987ab08a7db21a8a0b64f65727f54011) on the 24th of Jan 2010. It has been fixed in JQuery 1.4.1 which was released on the 26th of Jan 2010.

See: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5835

Comment: That bug report has nothing to do with this bug. Did I miss something?